# como puedo poner un div debajo de otro (css)

Tags: css

Hola estoy intentando poner un div debajo de otro:

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="lowNav">
<a href="#" class="search">&nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;</a>
<a href="#" class="nav">&nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div class="searchbox">
<form action="http://google.com" method="get" target="_self"><input type="hidden" name="customize_messenger_channel" value="preview-0"><input type="hidden" name="customize_changeset_uuid" value="639cac79-978a-4d85-8d32-584c9d1c87d9"><button name="search" class="btn">
<span>
</span></button>
<input type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" value=""></form>
<div class="autocomplete" style="display: none;">
</div></div><div class="nav">
     <ul class="sections">
<li>
<div class="menu"><ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-69"><a href="http://google.com" target="_self">shele</a></li>
</ul></div>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div></div></div>
```

pero el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

My css:

```
.wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.searchbox,
.nav{
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline;/*for IE 7 */
    *zoom:1;/*for IE 7 */
    vertical-align:top;
}
.searchbox {            
    background-color:#ff0;
}

.nav {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Como podria ponerlo uno debajo de otro o al menos porque en el codigo que puse no me lopone en ese orden?

ejemplo jsfiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/xcSXA/272/

Comment: El código que has colocado tiene errores de sintaxis o está incompleto. Si necesitas ayuda procura hacerlo mas fácil para el resto de nosotros.

Comment: edite el css espero que con eso se haya creo corregido el error. tambien edite el html por si acaso. tambien puse el ejemplo jsfiddle en el cual se ejecuta bien.

Comment: ¿y cual div va debajo de cual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que sea mas o menos lo que buscas

solo tienes que quitarle la propiedad de **css** `display:inline-block` que en pocas palabras lo que hace es poner los objetos uno al lado del otro.

Saludos espero te ayude.

```css
.wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.searchbox,
.nav{
    /*display: inline-block;
    *display:inline;/*for IE 7 */
    *zoom:1;/*for IE 7 */
    vertical-align:top;
}
.searchbox {            
    background-color:#ff0;
}

.nav {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="lowNav">
<a href="#" class="search">&nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;</a>
<a href="#" class="nav">&nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div class="searchbox">
<form action="http://google.com" method="get" target="_self"><input type="hidden" name="customize_messenger_channel" value="preview-0"><input type="hidden" name="customize_changeset_uuid" value="639cac79-978a-4d85-8d32-584c9d1c87d9"><button name="search" class="btn">
<span>
</span></button>
<input type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" value=""></form>
<div class="autocomplete" style="display: none;">
</div></div><div class="nav">
     <ul class="sections">
<li>
<div class="menu"><ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-69"><a href="http://google.com" target="_self">shele</a></li>
</ul></div>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div></div></div>
```